# Migration script MongoDB/NestJS

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

I have clubs in my app which will have experience field in each document of my club collection. On base of that experience I would like to create new fields - level and expToNextLvl. Is it possible to write such script which will update level and expToNextLvl everytime when experience changes? For example when there is update in document which increases experience, fields as level and expToNextLvl would be updated accordingly? The other question is if the migration script is the best thing to do so (I don't think if I fully understand its concept).

I have written example script which would do so.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClubRepository } from '@shared/lib/mongo/entities/club';

@Injectable()
export class ClubMigrationService {
  constructor(private clubRepository: ClubRepository) {}

  async migrate(levels: number[]) {
    const clubs = await this.clubRepository.find();

    for (const club of clubs) {
      // Calculate the club's level based on the amount of experience it has
      const experience = club.experience;
      let lvl = 1;
      for (let i = levels.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (experience >= levels[i]) {
          lvl = i + 1;
          break;
        }
      }

      // Calculate the amount of experience required to reach the next level
      let expToNextLvl = 0;
      if (lvl < levels.length) {
        const expForCurrentLvl = levels[lvl - 1];
        const expForNextLvl = levels[lvl];
        const expToReachNextLvl = expForNextLvl - expForCurrentLvl;
        const expAtCurrentLvl = experience - expForCurrentLvl;
        expToNextLvl = expToReachNextLvl - expAtCurrentLvl;
        if (expToNextLvl < 0) {
          expToNextLvl = 0;
        }
      }

      // Update the club document with the new experience, expToNextLvl, and lvl fields
      await this.clubRepository.findOneAndUpdate(club._id, {
        $set: {
          experience,
          expToNextLvl,
          lvl,
        },
      });
    }
  }
}
```

If its more or less correct how would I have to use it so it is invoked everytime that experience actually changes?

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are not the best place to do this as they are intented for one time run.

If you need to update specific fields every time `experience` is changed for any user then the best place to do that is `TypeORM` `@BeforeUpdate` hook or `Mongoose` pre save hook (depending on which ODM you use).
There you can put business logic similar to.

```
@Entity()
export class Clud {

    @BeforeUpdate()
    updateLevel() {
        // TODO Add here your business logic to update level fields
        // this.level = (this.experience / 2000) + 1;
    }
}
```